VCTargetsPath is not defined when running dotnet / msbuild
I've seen many topics with that problem, but no real solution anywhere.
I already tried fresh installs of VS / dotnet without success.
When trying to run dotnet pack on a C# - C++\CLI - C++ solution I ran into an MB4019 error because Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props is not found.
This is because the environment variable VCTargetsPath is not defined.
From my understanding, this variable should not be defined but instead populated when msbuild is called as the path it's pointing toward depends on which VS version will be used for the build.
Right now I have to set the variable in my system, which is bad. The Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props is referenced in all three projects above but I'm unsure about it's real use.
The build itself is working fine, it's only when I want to pack the project as an NuGet package that the problem arises.
How could I fix it ? I will not use npm to reinstall an older version of VS (I already tried anyway and it didn't work).

Are you building on Windows with Visual Studio installed and with C++ support installed in Visual Studio? Are you running the dotnet pack command in a "Developer Command Prompt for VS 20##" or equivalent (meaning vsdevcmd.bat has been run)?

yes I am running from the Developer Command Prompt, VS is installed with C++ 143

The dotnet tool has an embedded copy of msbuild and dotnet build is msbuild -t:build. However, msbuild -t:pack and dotnet pack are not the same implementation. The C++ project support (e.g. files like Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props) are shipped with Visual Studio but are not part of the .NET SDK. dotnet pack may only be using the SDK. msbuild -t:pack and dotnet pack both depend on using PackageReference in project files. Currently PackageReference is not supported for C++.

This issue should come from the installation issue.
Sometimes, visual studio installation lacks something by some means.
You can try to re-install everything, or try to repair the visual studio.
And you can check this:
MSBuild does not contain a value for the "VCTargetsPath" property
